# What is React's createClass's parameter look like exactly? Is it an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I feel like I've seen both versions of React's creatClass, with the former being more apparent in the docs. Is there any differences between the 2 other than the stylistic ones? Just seems weird that the first style looks like it's accepting an object, whereas the second is just a scope with any functions you want to throw at it.

```
var Greeting = React.createClass({
  someFunction: function () {
    ...
  },

  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      name: 'Mary'
    };
  },

  // ...

});
```

vs.

```
var Greeting = React.createClass({
  someFunction () {
    ...
  }

  getDefaultProps () {
    return {
      name: 'Mary'
    };
  }

  // ...

});
```

Comment: The latter is ECMAScript6

Comment: To expand on what Isaac said, the second option is just an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Method_definitions) with ES6 shorthand method definitions.

Comment: in the object literal doc, they use commas, but I don't see commas being used in other work, is that optional?

Comment: Your second example would fail without commas. What you're thinking of is using `class Greeting extends React.Component { method1() {} method2() {} }`

Comment: Can you show where you saw these? Your second example needs commas between functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not with `react`. It is a ES6 feature called [Object Literals](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-object-literal-features-in-depth)

```
const a = 10;

const b = {
  a, //which is equal to a: a 
}

function a(){}

const c = {
  a, //which is equal to a: function a(){}
}
```